# Could not list the users in the Office 365 domain with administrator credentials using graph api

Tags: rest, azure, go, office365

I am trying to list the users in an office 365 domain. I am using the graph API. I registered my application in azure AD with Directory.Read permissions. I am able to retrieve an access token, but when I try to send a request to list the users it returns an error:

```
 {"odata.error":{"code":"Request_DataContractVersionMissing","message":{"lang":"en",
  "value":"The specified api-version is invalid. The value must exactly match a supported 
   version."}}}
```

This is the request I make:

```
apiUrl := "https://graph.windows.net/"
    resource := "vstoregrid.com/users"
    data := url.Values{}
    data.Set("api-version", "2013-04-05")
    authbear := "Bearer "
    authbear += accessobj.Access_token

    u, _ := url.ParseRequestURI(apiUrl)
    u.Path = resource
    urlStr := fmt.Sprintf("%v", u)

    client := &http.Client{}

    r, _ := http.NewRequest("GET", urlStr, bytes.NewBufferString(data.Encode()))
    r.Header.Add("Content-Type", "application/json")
    r.Header.Set("Authorization", authbear)
    r.Header.Add("Host", "graph.windows.net")
    r.Header.Add("Content-Length", strconv.Itoa(len(data.Encode())))
```

I am using the version as specified in the documentation. Where am I going wrong?

Answer (score 1):

As the error message says in the result:

> The specified api-version is invalid. The value must exactly match a supported 
>      version.

You specified api version:

```
data.Set("api-version", "2014-04-05")
```

`"2014-04-05"` is not a valid api version. See the list of [supported versions here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/dn835125.aspx).

Supported versions:

- `"1.5"`
- `"2013-11-08"`
- `"2013-04-05"`

Most likely you wanted to use the api version `"2013-04-05"`:

```
data.Set("api-version", "2013-04-05")
```

Comment: thanks icza . I tried using that version "2013-04-05" it throws me the same error

Comment: @AishwaryaGopalakrishnan Please try other versions too, the most recent `"1.5"` too.

Comment: Thanks icza . I tried using all the versions but i get the same error .

Comment: issue solved . The mistake was in the way i sent the get request